# Can't load an SQL dump into Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was given an SQL dump from an Oracle 11g database. It contains all of the statements to reproduce the database. Unfortunately, it fails at the very first one

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "XXX"."YYY"
    INCREMENT BY 1
    START WITH 129004
    MAXVALUE 1000000000000000000000000000
    NOMINVALUE
    NOCYCLE
    CACHE 20
    NOORDER
GO
```

With the error `SQL command not properly ended`.  If I throw out the `GO` at the end, the error `user or role '' does not exist`.  What am I doing wrong?  I tried this both in `sqlplus` command line client and in Oracle SQL developer.

Needless to say, I'm very new to Oracle, so please be easy on me :D.

Comment: `Go`'s a sign that dump didn't come from on Oracle database. You'll probably have heaps of problems with it.

Comment: The `GO` looks like this was generated using a Microsoft tool - definitely not a regular Oracle dump.

Comment: When Oracle folks talk about a "dump", they are typically talking about a binary file created using the `export` utility (classic or DataPump).  It sounds like you have plain text file of SQL statements.  The `go` statements are all going to be invalid, that's not valid Oracle syntax.  Beyond that, does the `XXX` user exist in the database?  Are you logged in as `XXX` or as a user (generally a DBA) that would be expected to be able to create objects in the `XXX` schema?

Comment: @Mat, I think it was dumped from Aqua Datastudio, but maybe using middleware.

Comment: @JustinCave so the first "XXX" before the dot is the user? Is it ok if I leave it just as "YYY"?

Comment: @AndresRovira - `XXX` is the schema name (which is the same as the name of the user that owns the schema).  If you remove the `XXX` and just have `YYY`, the sequence would be created in the current schema.